# To show that there is no $l$ that satisfies a certain property.

Tags: proof-writing

Let $f \in C[a,b]$ define $\|f\| _{1} =\int_{a}^{b} |f|.$

(b)Show that there is no number $l$ such that$\|f\|_{\max} \leq l \|f\| _{1}, 
\forall f \in C[a,b].$

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=n(\frac  1 n-x) $ for $0 \leq x\leq \frac  1n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x> \frac 1 n$. Then the sup norm tends to $\infty$ but the $L^{1}$ norm is bounded.

In fact the sup norm of $f_n$ is $1$ and  $\int_0^{1} |f_n(t)| dt=\frac  1 {2n}$.

Note: you can easily transform this example to get a similar sequence on any interval $[a,b]$: define $g_n(x)=f_n(\frac  {x-a} {b-a})$.

Comment: how did you think  about this example?

Comment: so mine will not work?

Comment: @Emptymind Your example works only fro certain values of $a$ and $b$. It works if $|a|<1$ and $|b| <1$.

Comment: How did you think about this example?

Comment: how I can transform it?

Comment: I have given the construction for any $[a,b]$ now.  The idea for $(f_n)$ is to make $\|f_n\|_1$ bounded but $\|f_n\|_{max}$ go to $\infty$. For the second property it is enough if $f_n(0) \to \infty$. Now maker $f_n$ $0$ outside some small interval around $0$ to get the first property. @Emptymind

Comment: I think the supremum norm is 1 and not $n$ in your example on [0,1]. correct?

Comment: @Emptymind You are right. The supremum is $1$.

Comment: Now for the adjusted sequence of functions the supremum norm is $1 + \frac{a n}{b-a}$ while the other norm is $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n(b-a)} + \frac{a}{b-a}$ which is bounded by 1..... are my calculations correct?

Comment: Check your calculations again. The supremum of $g_n$ is $1$ and $\int_a^{b} g_n(x)dx=(b-a)\int_0^{1} f_n(y)dy=\frac {b-a} {2n}$. @Emptymind

Comment: $y = \frac {x - a}{b-a}$?

Comment: Yes. That is the substitution you have to make.

Comment: And what are the bounds for $x$ in your new function $g$? are they still  $0 \leq x \leq (1/n)$?

Comment: @Emptymind There is no need to worry about that. Once you know $\|f_n\|_{\infty}$ and $\int |f_n|$ simply make the substitution to find the corresponding numbers for $g_n$. Don't go back to the definition of $f_n$.

Comment: but the integral of |f_{n}| = (1/2n) how can I make substitution in this ?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, let $[a,b]=[-1,1]$. Consider $f_{n}(x)=-1$ for $-1\leq x\leq -1/n$ and $f_{n}(x)=x$ for $-1/n\leq x\leq 1/n$, and $f_{n}(x)=1$ for $1/n\leq x\leq 1$.

Argue that $\{f_{n}\}$ is Cauchy in $L^{1}$, then by the assumption, we have $\{f_{n}\}$ being Cauchy in $\sup$ norm, but the limit point is not a continuous function, a contradiction.